# mysql replace nan with 0, cannot find any documentation

Tags: mysql

How do I accomplish this in a query? I handle the result in a pandas dataframe and am using `df.fillna(0)` right now. I would like to do it directly in the sql request, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sql query you can use `coalesce`. It would be this way:

```
SELECT coalesce(column1,0)
from table
```

What it does `coalesce` is get the first value not `NULL`, this is, in my example, if the value you get in `column1` is `NULL`, it will get 0, so it returns the first non `NULL` argument. You can use it with more arguments:

```
SELECT coalesce(column1,column2,0)
from table
```

This will return if `column1` is not NULL will return `column1`. 
If `column1` is NULL, and `column2` is not NULL will return `column2`
If `column1` is NULL and `column2` is also NULL, it will return 0

You can read more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but I never saw that those values were indeed `null` in the database and not `NaN` as I thought. For some reason, pandas converts `null` to `NaN`, so I didn't know what to do about that.